# Retrieve an upload image to the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to retrieve an image from database. I created a SimpleVote database and profiledata table,  I uploaded candidate details successfully. Now I want to retrieve the uploaded image. 
My code is:

```
<?php

require("db/db.php");


$sql = "SELECT path FROM profiledata";

$res = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

if($res){

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        echo "<img src=".$row['path']."/>";
    }
}
else{
    echo "Error : " . mysqli_error($db); 
}


mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

but I didn't get the uploaded image.

Comment: This seems like valid display code. Maybe your upload code didn't insert the right record?

Comment: `var_dump($res)`, `print_r($row)`

Comment: Is the filepath making it into the database. Are you receiving any errors. Does it print out the img tag, but no "src"? What is the exact problem here. "didn't get uploaded image" is not terribly specific.

Comment: I retrieved it this way <td><a href=".$row['path'].">Profile image</a></td> then I got image through this link. But I want it as a image.

Comment: I want to retrieve image without link, by <img> tag

Comment: So.. it works when you do it as an `href` in an `<a>` tag, but not when it's the `src` in an `<img>` tag? Is that right?

Comment: I didn't got any errors. image displayed as a small square without colour image.

Comment: It is wrong. but I cannot identify what is the wrong here.

Comment: Thankx for your help..